Subdomain Resolution error when deploying application on Dokku via Jenkins
Question:
I'm having trouble accessing my Spring Boot application after deploying it on Dokku using Jenkins. Here’s a detailed overview of my setup and the steps I've taken so far. Both Jenkins and Dokku are running in separate Docker containers.
My Setup

Containers: Dokku and Jenkins are each running in isolated Docker containers.

Dokku App: Deployed a Spring Boot application on Dokku via Jenkins.


This is my  docker compose file to run Dokku in a container:
services:
  dokku:
    image: dokku/dokku:0.35.5
    container_name: dokku
    networks:
      - jenkins_dokku  
    ports:
      - "3022:22"
      - "8081:80"
      - "8443:443"
    volumes:
      - "/var/lib/dokku:/mnt/dokku"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
    environment:
      DOKKU_HOSTNAME: dokku.me
      DOKKU_HOST_ROOT: /var/lib/dokku/home/dokku
      DOKKU_LIB_HOST_ROOT: /var/lib/dokku/var/lib/dokku
    restart: unless-stopped

networks:
  jenkins_dokku:
    external: true 

This is my docker file to run jenkins:
FROM jenkins/jenkins:2.462.3-jdk17
USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y lsb-release
RUN curl -fsSLo /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.asc \
  https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg
RUN echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) \
  signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.asc] \
  https://download.docker.com/linux/debian \
  $(lsb_release -cs) stable" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y docker-ce-cli
USER jenkins
RUN jenkins-plugin-cli --plugins "blueocean docker-workflow"

Steps I Followed for Deployment

Deployment: Used Jenkins to automate the deployment of my Spring Boot application on Dokku.

Generated Subdomain: After deployment, Dokku generated the following subdomain:

http://saamfi2-backend-mod.dokku.me/



Ports Configuration Check: Verified Dokku’s port mapping for my app:

dokku ports:report saamfi2-backend-mod


Output:

Port map: http:9101:9091

Detected ports: http:80:5000



Smoke Test with Hosts File: Added an entry in my Windows hosts file to perform a basic smoke test:

127.0.0.1 saamfi2-backend-mod.dokku.me




The Issue
When I try to access http://saamfi2-backend-mod.dokku.me/, it doesn’t resolve correctly. I suspect the issue may be related to:

Incorrect port mapping in Dokku.

Potential IP address conflict or misconfiguration in the hosts file, especially since both Dokku and Jenkins are running in Docker containers.


Could anyone advise on troubleshooting steps or suggest a solution for correct port mapping and DNS resolution in this Dockerized Dokku setup?
